# How to represent a non-Beneficial criterion in PROMETHEE II method?

Tags: python, mcdm

I am trying to solve a Multi Criteria Decision Making problem using The PROMETHEE Method, and I have come across PyDecision Library for Python that contains all PROMETHEE Versions, Yet in their [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/143TUtTBy9y6gW0kMVAfhANBhuw1bKvBB?usp=sharing) demo they have used an abstract example that has only Beneficial Criterions.

Let's say I want to solve this problem:

| Alternat | Cost (NB) | RAM (B) | Storage (B) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Phone1 | 500 $ | 16 GB | 64 GB |
| Phone2 | 350 $ | 8 GB | 32 GB |

Cost: is a non-beneficial criterion because we want to minimize its value.
Ram & Storage: are Beneficial criterions because we want to maximize these values.

So, is there a way to present the type of criterion to PROMETHEE?

Comment: I'm not a domain expert, but... is there any reason you couldn't just negate the costs?

Comment: I thought about doing that tbh, but in theory PROMETHEE works with 2 different formulas, one if the criterion is Beneficial and the other formula if it is non-beneficial.